# Baisic table layout background or container issue mainly on Apple device's

Tags: html, ios, css

So the title pretty much say's it all, In case anyone is interested I'm self thought so please don't be so hasty to say I did no research or put any effort into this because I've messed around with a lot of various things on this somewhat BS page and searched using Google Yahoo and Bing looking for a similar issue. Basically the table layout seems to to get like a default transparent overlay, I noticed its only directly on the table because the background images are clearly visible when scrolling past the top of the page and its visible in each table cell. 
Like I said I've tried various things with no luck but if this is just some common newbie mistake please point me to some reading material or even a good book for web design as I could really use the know how and wouldn't mind learning something as apposed to shooting in the dark with random bits of HTML, CSS and JavaScript in the little free time I do have..

*Also I was doing all this using blogger as my "host" mainly because I plan to ingrate the blogger framework or whatever into the page after I know its good to go. Find a link to the page below, If you need the raw HTML not formatted to blogger just let me know.
https://layout-dev.blogspot.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the image host for the body background-image wasn't loading in the image on apple device's, still not sure why but after relocating the image to my personal Dropbox and directly linking to it that solved the problem. *As weird as that may sound the original url was http://subtlepatterns.com/patterns/binding_dark.png and simply replacing it with https://dl.dropbox.com/s/njcu65h90cmsbp8/binding_dark.png solved the problem. -Figured I should post the answer just in case someone ever has a similar issue.